# Why doesn't this code work for an svg element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

This code works well when i have it set as a canvas. But when i want to use it on an svg element, i get nothing. What i am trying to do is get the mouse coordinates relative to the canvas but then draw svg shapes depending on where the user clicks.

It works with this html:

```
<section class=chartArea>
    <canvas id=svg></canvas>
</section>
```

This html does not work:

```
<section class=chartArea>
   <svg id=svg></svg>
</section>
```

javascript:

```
svg = document.getElementById("svg");

function relMouseCoords(event){
  var totalOffsetX = 0; //coordinates of corner of canvas
  var totalOffsetY = 0;
  var canvasX = 0;
  var canvasY = 0;
  var svg = this; //what called the event

  do{
      totalOffsetX += svg.offsetLeft - svg.scrollLeft; //relative coordinates
      totalOffsetY += svg.offsetTop - svg.scrollTop;
  }
  while(svg = svg.offsetParent)

  canvasX = event.pageX - totalOffsetX;
  canvasY = event.pageY - totalOffsetY;

  point = {x:canvasX, y:canvasY};

  console.log(canvasX + " " + canvasY);

  return point; //object returned
}

svg.addEventListener('mousemove', relMouseCoords);
```

Comment: It works me, http://jsfiddle.net/j3nneh5z/ (write coords into console)

Comment: In the console i just get "NaN NaN"

Comment: Strange, in Safari/mac I get there coords. It means there is problem with any browser. Which one?

Comment: Yeah i just checked chrome, which worked fine. I was getting the problem in firefox developer edition

Comment: The comparison of `<canvas>` and `<svg>` on the W3Schools website [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp) might be helpful

Comment: Even I'm getting the coordinates in safari/mac no issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CSSOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-htmlelement-interface) offsetLeft and offsetTop are html only properties and do not exist for SVG elements.

Firefox implements this correctly but Chrome does not.

You'd be better off using getBoundingClientRect instead I think.